# Object to class instance typecasting failing in normal debugging but passing in evaluate mode

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8

Its very basic, and its boggling my mind now.

The specific exception message that i see is :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
com.company.client.vehicle.model.PerceivedGarageMessageDTO cannot be cast to com.company.client.vehicle.model.PerceivedGarageMessageDTO
```

The code looks like this

```
PerceivedGarageMessageDTO p = (PerceivedGarageMessageDTO)obj;
```

I am using Intellij.

When i view obj in intellij watcher, i see the relevant properties inside obj.
When i evaluate `PerceivedGarageMessageDTO p = (PerceivedGarageMessageDTO)obj`  in evaluate mode, the execution goes fine and the object is typecasted.
When i execute the command in normal debug run by pressing F8, an exception is thrown.

I am unable to figure out the cause of this very very strange issue.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when the class is loaded with different classloaders.
Will fix debugger evaluator within [IDEA-203275](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-203275).